# SQL Server 2019 Bug with User Defined Functions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

In SQL Server 2019 (Beta) this code now returns a list of just one value. If the compatibility is set back to 2017 or earlier this will return a list with five values. The same bug shows up also if you are doing a math function. For instance if a customer is doing something like a old school rolling total report that also uses a user defined function they possibly could be bitten by this.

If this is actually intended functionality surely it needs to be documented as it will break quite a bit of existing code.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SomeStringFunction] 
    (@value NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS 
BEGIN 
    RETURN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ISNULL(@value, '')); 
END 
GO

DECLARE @str VARCHAR(1000)

SELECT TOP(5) @str = dbo.SomeStringFunction(@str) + ',' + name 
FROM sys.columns

SELECT @str
```

I would expect this to return the same in all versions of SQL Server.

Comment: Now that we have STRING_AGG, SUM OVER ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING etc there shouldn't be a need for nasty variable-abuse hacks like this? I'm certain this will always have been one of those "undocumented, unsupported, behavior could change at any time" tricks, and whaddya know; it changed

Comment: This looks like an issue for [support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/sql-server-ver15-release-notes?view=sqlallproducts-allversions#support). Microsoft will either care about this breaking or not (and I strongly suspect the answer will be "not", if keeping the compat level down is enough) but whether it cares or not isn't up to any of us. The semantics of this were *never* formally guaranteed; this is pretty much the definition of a non-deterministic query. In 2019 there are alternatives for this and implementing those should be part of the upgrade path.

Comment: If you are writing that function in SQL Server 2019, i would suggest making use of the in-line scalar function syntax. I don't really understand the point of it though, it's just a userdefined version of `ISNULL({Some String},'')` Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: My theory for why this breaks (without having a 2019 instance at the moment to try this out) is because of the optimizations made in evaluating scalar user-defined functions. You know, the thing you've got there that has awful performance because it inhibits parallelism and forces row-by-row evaluation. The 2019 optimizer is now finally capable of inlining them into queries (if they're not too complicated) and that's probably what's breaking this trick, why requires row-by-row evaluation. If given a choice between keeping this and finally having fast functions, I know where my money goes...

Comment: For our product I need to support back to SQL 2012. We do drop support for 2012 but not for another 6 months. As you can guess dropping support for SQL 2014 is quite a ways away. So no String_agg for us for quite a few years.  :(

Comment: Then use the "classic" `FOR XML PATH` & `STUFF` solution

Comment: As of writing, SQL Server 2019 will support compatibility levels all the way back to 100 (2008), so a simple workaround is to just leave that alone. Of course this will mean you miss out on newer features and optimizer improvements, but that's more or less also exactly what you want if you need hacks like these to keep working.

Comment: Also, if my theory is correct and this is caused by scalar UDF inlining, [here's how to turn that off](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining#disabling-scalar-udf-inlining-without-changing-the-compatibility-level) without dropping the compat level. This can be done per database, per query and even per function (`WITH INLINE = OFF`). If that fixes it, I'd say the change is both documented, and has plenty of effective workarounds with minimal impact -- i.e. not a bug.

Comment: We have over seven thousand stored procs and lots of triggers so finding the incompatible code is difficult.  I tried this regular expression SELECT\s*(@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\s*=.*vf.*.\1.  Which found about 9 places that we have problems but I have trouble if the problem code is split over multiple lines since SQL doesn't require a semicolon on the end of SQL statements writing a regular expression to hunt this down is a mess.  Once the bad code is located it is pretty easy to fix by just removing the user defined functions and just using regular SQL functions.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed and tested with SQL 2019 CTP 3.2 this morning and it looks like the issue may be fixed.  :)